# Debug Area warning in Xcode 7.0.1 for iOS 9 for Game Center

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios9, game-center

I made my app in Xcode 6.1 and I had no warnings in debug area for iOS 9. Now I upgraded to Xcode 7.0.1 and I get a GameCenter warning in debug area for iOS 9:

**14 13:39:20.607 MachineMan[265:13165] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterAuthenticateExtension invalidated**

**2015-10-14 13:39:25.027 MachineMan[265:13058] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior ()
plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated**

What is this saying about Game Center? It appears to be working fine when I sign in and out. Leaderboards work fine so why do I get this message in debug area?

Answer (score 1):

I get this log in the consol when I try to present *GameCenter* achievements **UIViewController**: **GKGameCenterViewController** while the Player isn't signed in the *GameCenter*. An **UIAlertController** is presented :

> Game Center Unavailable
>
> Player is not signed in
>
> OK

The result is a stuck UI.

Checking the player state prevent this problem.

PS : I'm testing on an iPhone 6s **iOS 9.0.2** with **xCode 7.0**.

Comment: Is this an issue my app can get rejected over? Do I have to change the game center implementation code or something else? Or is this a bug in iOS 9 and Xcode like many and I mean many Xcode 7 bugs that are currently present that are out of the control of developer.

Comment: Did you get an answer about this? Is this a bug, or something that needs fixing?